# multiple cache options for Knitr results

Tags: r, knitr

How can I clarify that I want results held and as-is?  I have tried the following:

````
```{r testing, echo=TRUE, results=list('hold', 'asis')}
require(xtable)
print(xtable(data.frame(Temp=mean(airquality$Temp))), type = "html", include.rownames = FALSE)
tab <- head(airquality)
```
````

however, the results are not printed "as-is" and the log states:

> Warning in if (options$results == "hold") { :   the condition has
>   length > 1 and only the first element will be used

**Screenshot of output (using results=list('hold', 'asis')):** Hold enforced (table displayed at end of chunk); as-is not enforced (table not formatted)
[image]

**Screenshot of output (using results=list('asis', 'hold')):** Hold not enforced (table displayed mid-chunk); as-is enforced (table formatted)
[image]

**Session info:**
[image]

Comment: How were the results printed?  Please give us more info, your code works fine for me.

Comment: @RichardScriven: Have added screenshot of output (note table formats as-is if I instead place 'hold' prior to 'asis', however 'hold' is ignored).

Comment: How was `hold` ignored?  Do you mean the package load message?

Comment: By hold ignored I meant that the table is displayed mid chunk as opposed to at the end of the chunk - have added a screen shot to the original posting.

Comment: This is not possible at the moment. The `results` option must take a single character string.

Comment: +1 this would be nice